# Does Javascript Support Excel ChartObjects?

Tags: javascript, excel

Does JS support Excel chartobjects. I found a reference link to use, but when I try, I get Object doesnt support this property or method.

Reference Link:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13283/Standard-of-Excellence

Error Line:
var chartObj = Sheet.ChartObjects.Add(chartLeftPixels, 
               chartTopPixels, chartWidthPixels, chartHeightPixels);

Answer (score 0):

Initialize ChartObjects as

```
var co = Sheet.ChartObjects();
var ch = co.Add(chartLeftPixels, chartTopPixels, chartWidthPixels, chartHeightPixels);
```